# Building svelte app as a set of static files

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I want to use Svelte in my next project, due to its clean syntax and how nice is to work in it. Unfortunately, to deploy the app in my company I can't use `node` or anything like that on the server. I can only serve the app from `nginx` as static files.

Is it possible in svelte? I can't find anything that would allow me to do that, all solutions I've tried like `@sveltejs/adapter-static` didn't seem to generate it correctly to use it in this way. I can't find any guide on how to do that on the web.

Answer (score 13):

In order to pre-render a SvelteKit 1.0 static site you need to:

1. Install the static adapter with `npm i -D @sveltejs/adapter-static`
2. Put the following in `svelte.config.js`

```
/**
 * from https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static
 */
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

export default {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown. On some platforms
            // these options are set automatically — see below
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false,
            strict: true
        })
    }
};
```

3. Add to `devDependencies` in `package.json` (you can remove the default adapter-auto):

```
    "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "next",
```

4. Add the following line to `src/routes/+layout.js` - create the file if it does not exist:

```
    export const prerender = true;
```

5. Run `npm run build`

The static files will be generated in the `build` directory.

More details at https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static and https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#sveltejsadapter-static

Comment: Does this render out the DOM or does JS still need to create the DOM? Is there an option for both?

Answer (score 7):

If you aren't using SvelteKit, you can just copy contents of `/build/` generated by `npm run build`. This should work.

Comment: Quite right. When posting my answer, I think I overthought things. :-D

Answer (score 2):

I think [Libertas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71706327/157247) posted a couple of weeks after this is most likely what you're looking for.

But I'll leave the below here anyway in case it's useful to you or someone else coming along later:

---

[SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) (from the Svelte core team) supports server-side rendering, and [documents generating static sites](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters#supported-environments-static-sites):

> **Static Sites**
>
> Most adapters will generate static HTML for any prerenderable pages of your site. **In some cases, your entire app might be prerenderable, in which case you can use `@sveltejs/adapter-static@next` to generate static HTML for all your pages.** A fully static site can be hosted on a wide variety of platforms, including static hosts like GitHub Pages.

*(my emphasis)*