# Docker: SvelteKit app cannot be accessed from browser

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, svelte, sveltekit

I've got a Svelte (with Sveltekit) app which I just containerized. It builds correctly and there are no errors when running, but I cannot access it from the browser. I tried accessing `http://localhost:5050/` and also `http://0.0.0.0:5050/` but I'm getting:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

This is the `Dockerfile` I'm using:

```
# Our Node base image
FROM node:19-alpine

# Set the Node environment to development to ensure all packages are installed
ENV NODE_ENV development

# Change our current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy over `package.json` and lock files to optimize the build process
COPY  package.json package-lock.json ./
# Install Node modules
RUN npm install

# Copy over rest of the project files
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Expose port
ENV PORT 5050
EXPOSE 5050

# Run `yarn dev` and set the host to 0.0.0.0 so we can access the web app from outside
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

This is how I'm building it:
`docker build -t sveltekit:node --network=host .`

And this is how I'm running it:
`docker run -d -p 5050:5050 --name sveltekit-app sveltekit:node`

And this is the output of running `docker ps`:

```
a9e241b09fd3 

IMAGE            
sveltekit:node

COMMAND 
"docker-entrypoint.s…"                 

CREATED      
About a minute ago        

STATUS
Up About a minute              

PORTS          
0.0.0.0:5050->5050/tcp          

NAMES
sveltekit-app
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

**Container Logs**

```
2022-11-30 19:09:18 
2022-11-30 19:09:18 > dundermifflin-ui@0.0.1 start
2022-11-30 19:09:18 > export PORT=8080 && node ./build
2022-11-30 19:09:18 
2022-11-30 19:09:18 Listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
```

why it is listening to port 8080? I updated my `package.json` to be:

`"dev": "vite dev --port=5050"`

meaning that I'm enforcing port 5050, isn't that right?

Comment: For reference, [here is our example SvelteKit based application running in Docker and its Dockerfile](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Comment: Short answer?: Try add the `--host` flag (`CMD ["npm", "run", "dev", "--host"]`)
Long answer: When you are running as "run dev", you are not actually using the output of the npm run build command, you are still running in "dev" mode. See this post for a longer tutorial, https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/tbu8sy/tutorial_how_to_build_a_sveltekit_docker_image_to/

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that sveltekit listens on port 5050?

Because when I start it up with npm run dev (vite dev) it usually takes port 5173 and if it is already used it counts 1 up until it reaches a free port.

Add in the package.json at the dev command a --port=5050.

Full string:

> "dev": "vite dev --port=5050",

Comment: Hi. Yes, when I run it locally (not in docker) it runs on port 5173. I have added `--port=5050` to package.json, rebuilt the container and ran it again yet I'm seeing the same result.

Comment: Can you look into the container logs with docker logs <container-id> and look if the server didn't crash and started up normally.

Comment: Interesting. I updated the logs in the question. It says that it is listening to port 8080, so I decided to add `EXPOSE 8080` to the Dockerfile but still cannot access it.

Comment: It should work but because you are in a docker container it could be the problem described by Oscar in the comment under your question maybe that's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your container has no web server running to serve your files.
As you are just wanting to serve static files, node [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) would probably do.

Try running this somewhere in your dockerfile..
`npm install --global http-server && http-server ./app -p 5050`

**EDIT:**
Sveltekit seems to run [@sveltejs/adapter-node](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node) to serve files.

Comment: thanks for your reply, let me try that. To be honest I'm pretty new with docker, I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVMG2nWjWk4&ab_channel=AryaPrakasa and the guy running it didn't seem to have added a server to the dockerfile

Comment: Are you using Svelte? or Sveltekit? they are different. I answered assuming svelte, not sveltekit. I am not sure how sveltekit works and if it has it's own way to serve the files. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71527665/building-svelte-app-as-a-set-of-static-files) questions and answers might be helpful to you.

Comment: My app uses Sveltekit.

Comment: Maybe you could check what is being served from within the container itself by logging in to the container and checking from within there.

Comment: Ok, I logged into the container, what should I be looking for? the build folder's contents?

Comment: if your in the container, your in the machine running the site, so you could maybe check what port sveltekit is listening on. eg "sudo netstat -lntup". or maybe event try requesting the page "curl 128.0.0.1:5050" if you know it's running on 5050

Answer (score 0):

In the `Dockerfile` try to change:

`CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]`

to

`CMD ["npm", "run", "dev", "--", "-p", "5050]`

Then rebuild your docker image and run it again.

Comment: just tried this, but didn't work, I'm getting the same result

Comment: Do you continue to see `Listening on 0.0.0.0:8080` in the docker container logs?